# Prove $log(f)$ is subharmonic using Laplacian operator

Tags: real-analysis, partial-derivative, harmonic-functions, laplacian

I am proving that $g(x,y)=\log(f(x,y))$ is a subharmonic function on $G$, if $f:G\to\mathbb{R}$ is subharmonic in $G$ (open set of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$) with $f(x,y)>0$ for all $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^{2}$. For that, I want to prove that the laplacian
$$\Delta g=\frac{\partial^{2} g}{\partial x^{2}}+\frac{\partial^{2} g}{\partial y^{2}},$$
is greater or equal to zero in $G$. So, I start by computing the partial derivatives:
$$
\frac{\partial^{2} g(x,y)}{\partial x^{2}}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y)}{f(x,y)}\right)=\frac{\frac{\partial^{2} f}{\partial x^{2}}f(x,y)-\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y)\right)^{2}}{(f(x,y))^{2}}.
$$
$$
\frac{\partial^{2} g(x,y)}{\partial y^{2}}=\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(\frac{\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y)}{f(x,y)}\right)=\frac{\frac{\partial^{2} f}{\partial y^{2}}f(x,y)-\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y)\right)^{2}}{(f(x,y))^{2}}.
$$
Then, in $G$,
$$\Delta g=\frac{\partial^{2} g}{\partial x^{2}}+\frac{\partial^{2} g}{\partial y^{2}}=\frac{\Delta f\cdot f-\left[\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right)^{2}+\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right)^{2}\right]}{f^{2}}.$$
Taking on account my hypothesis ($\Delta f\geq 0$, $f>0$), for seeing that $\Delta g\geq 0$, I just have to prove that
$$
\Delta f\cdot f\geq\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right)^{2}+\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right)^{2}.
$$
And this last step is where I am stuck... Is this inequality true for all $(x,y)$?

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: Are you sure that the problem is stated is stated correctly? $f(x, y) = x^2+1$ is subharmonic and positive, but $\log f(x, y)$ is not subharmonic (unless I made an error).

Comment: @rubikman23 are you sure you didn’t mean superharmonic instead of subharmonic?

Comment: Thanks both for answering. I am seeing that the problem is badly stated...  I saw the example $\log(1+x^2+y^2)$ which is in the hypothesis of the problem, and thought It was general...